# Using awk to parse and transform the following log

Tags: linux, awk

I have a log like this:

```
DEBUG: Worker thread (#12) initialized
DEBUG: Worker thread (#19) initialized
DEBUG: Worker thread (#9) initialized
DEBUG: Worker thread (#15) initialized
DEBUG: Worker thread (#3) initialized
DEBUG: Worker thread (#17) initialized
DEBUG: Worker thread (#14) initialized
DEBUG: Worker thread (#16) initialized
Threads started!

[ 5s ] thds: 20 tps: 35265.85 qps: 35265.85 (r/w/o: 0.00/35265.85/0.00) lat (ms,99%): 2.52 err/s: 0.00 reconn/s: 0.00
[ 10s ] thds: 20 tps: 35965.67 qps: 35965.67 (r/w/o: 0.00/35965.67/0.00) lat (ms,99%): 2.03 err/s: 0.00 reconn/s: 0.00
...
```

I want to parse this log file and get all the following lines:

```
[ 5s ] thds: 20 tps: 35265.85 qps: 35265.85 (r/w/o: 0.00/35265.85/0.00) lat (ms,99%): 2.52 err/s: 0.00 reconn/s: 0.00
[ 10s ] thds: 20 tps: 35965.67 qps: 35965.67 (r/w/o: 0.00/35965.67/0.00) lat (ms,99%): 2.03 err/s: 0.00 reconn/s: 0.00
....
```

Then I want to transform those lines into the following format for plotting:

```
5,35265.85
10,35965.67
...
```

Here is my awk code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
awk '
BEGIN {
printf "#time,tps\n";
}
/^\[\ [0-9]{1,4}[s]?\ \]/ { # regex for [ 1050s ]
printf "%s,%s\n", substr($2,1, length($2)-1), $7
}
' "$@"
```

The thing I don't like for this solution is: I must count manually the index of tokens generated by awk. I prefer a better solution such as: "first token after string "tps"". This way, it will be more general and easier in parsing.

My question is: can I really do that using awk. Or are there any better solutions to handle my situation?

Comment: @Trần Kim Dự, Also please do mention the logic of getting the output in your post too, along with your attempts.

Comment: Why not `15s` and `30s`? What logic says just `5s` and `10s`?

Comment: @EdMorton I have updated. That is my fault. Basically, I want to get all numbers in result and separate by ",".

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I am apologized for not making it clear. I just want to get 2 lines for sample.

Comment: I will update my code what I have tried.

Comment: Do you only want to read the first two lines i.e for 5s and 10s and not for the lines below that in your logs?

Comment: Instead of paste original java code, I have updated my awk command line. Please take a look.

Comment: You're making your question far more confusing that it has to be by first posting 17 lines of sample input and then posting another 2 lines of sample input (ignoring the useless `...` line) then 2 lines of expected output then another 4 lines of expected (or is it actual?) output. Please clean up your question to simply show 1 block of sample input text and the associated 1 block of expected output text and make it clear what's expected vs current/actual output.

Comment: @EdMorton I have edited my question. I am very apologized for my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
$ awk -v OFS=',' '/^\[/{print $2+0, $5, $7, $9}' file
5,20,35265.85,35265.85
10,20,35965.67,35965.67
15,20,35233.82,35233.82
20,20,35239.05,35239.25
25,20,37188.61,37188.41
30,20,36622.32,36622.32
35,20,36538.27,36538.27
```

or maybe this if you want headers:

```
awk -F'[ :]+' -v OFS=',' '/^\[/{ if (!doneHdr++) print "time", $4, $6, $8; print $2+0, $5, $7, $9}' file
time,thds,tps,qps
5,20,35265.85,35265.85
10,20,35965.67,35965.67
15,20,35233.82,35233.82
20,20,35239.05,35239.25
25,20,37188.61,37188.41
30,20,36622.32,36622.32
35,20,36538.27,36538.27
```

or this:

```
$ awk -F'[ :]+' -v OFS=',' -v tgts='time thds tps qps' '
    BEGIN {
        numTags = split(tgts,tags)
        for (tagNr=1; tagNr<=numTags; tagNr++) {
            printf "%s%s", tags[tagNr], (tagNr<numTags ? OFS : ORS)
        }
    }
    /^\[/ {
        for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
            f[$i] = $(i+1)
            sub(/[^0-9]+$/,"",f[$i])
        }
        f["time"] = f["["]

        for (tagNr=1; tagNr<=numTags; tagNr++) {
            printf "%s%s", f[tags[tagNr]], (tagNr<numTags ? OFS : ORS)
        }
    }
' file
time,thds,tps,qps
5,20,35265.85,35265.85
10,20,35965.67,35965.67
15,20,35233.82,35233.82
20,20,35239.05,35239.25
25,20,37188.61,37188.41
30,20,36622.32,36622.32
35,20,36538.27,36538.27
```

I ran the above using your original sample input:

```
$ cat file
DEBUG: Worker thread (#12) initialized
DEBUG: Worker thread (#19) initialized
DEBUG: Worker thread (#9) initialized
DEBUG: Worker thread (#15) initialized
DEBUG: Worker thread (#3) initialized
DEBUG: Worker thread (#17) initialized
DEBUG: Worker thread (#14) initialized
DEBUG: Worker thread (#16) initialized
Threads started!

[ 5s ] thds: 20 tps: 35265.85 qps: 35265.85 (r/w/o: 0.00/35265.85/0.00) lat (ms,99%): 2.52 err/s: 0.00 reconn/s: 0.00
[ 10s ] thds: 20 tps: 35965.67 qps: 35965.67 (r/w/o: 0.00/35965.67/0.00) lat (ms,99%): 2.03 err/s: 0.00 reconn/s: 0.00
[ 15s ] thds: 20 tps: 35233.82 qps: 35233.82 (r/w/o: 0.00/35233.82/0.00) lat (ms,99%): 2.26 err/s: 0.00 reconn/s: 0.00
[ 20s ] thds: 20 tps: 35239.05 qps: 35239.25 (r/w/o: 0.00/35239.25/0.00) lat (ms,99%): 2.11 err/s: 0.00 reconn/s: 0.00
[ 25s ] thds: 20 tps: 37188.61 qps: 37188.41 (r/w/o: 0.00/37188.41/0.00) lat (ms,99%): 1.86 err/s: 0.00 reconn/s: 0.00
[ 30s ] thds: 20 tps: 36622.32 qps: 36622.32 (r/w/o: 0.00/36622.32/0.00) lat (ms,99%): 1.96 err/s: 0.00 reconn/s: 0.00
[ 35s ] thds: 20 tps: 36538.27 qps: 36538.27 (r/w/o: 0.00/36538.27/0.00) lat (ms,99%): 2.00 err/s: 0.00 reconn/s: 0.00
```

Comment: Thanks for the very detail answer. Your answer is my expected result. I am very apologized that my question is not clear that makes many people confuse. I am trying to understand every part of your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to do this. Assuming that your log file is called `data.txt`. You could run the following

```
cat data.txt | grep -wE "5s|10s" | awk '{print substr($(NF-16), 1, length($(NF-16))-1) "," $(NF-13) "," $(NF-11) "," $(NF-9)}'
```

#### Explanation

1. `cat <filename>` prints the file contents to the standard output
2. `grep -wE <exp>` filters the output from the cat and chooses lines containing the expression which in our case is `5s or 10s`. the `-w` ensures that only those lines which match the whole word are chosen or `5s` without `-w` also chooses `15s, 20s ..` etc..,

This will choose the following lines on which `awk` is run

```
[ 5s ] thds: 20 tps: 35265.85 qps: 35265.85 (r/w/o: 0.00/35265.85/0.00) lat (ms,99%): 2.52 err/s: 0.00 reconn/s: 0.00
[ 10s ] thds: 20 tps: 35965.67 qps: 35965.67 (r/w/o: 0.00/35965.67/0.00) lat (ms,99%): 2.03 err/s: 0.00 reconn/s: 0.00
```

3. Using `awk` we can use `NF` to find out the number of fields in each line `awk '{print NF}'` i.e. 18

Extract the corresponding the contents which are at `NF-16`, `NF-13`, `NF-11` and `NF-9`th positions. i.e. 2nd, 5th, 7th and 9th positions respectively. However, the 2nd position is `5s|10s` etc.., and you want to remove the tailing `s` which can be done by `substr($2, 1, length($2)-1)` i.e. from 1st character to the length of 5s / 10s i.e. 2/3 accordingly and removing the last character (s) using `-1`.

Your final command is

```
awk '{print substr($(NF-16), 1, length($(NF-16))-1) "," $(NF-13) "," $(NF-11) "," $(NF-9)}'
```

and can be replaced as

```
awk '{print substr($2, 1, length($2)-1)","$5","$7","$9}'
```

Putting it all together you have

```
cat data.txt | grep -wE "5s|10s" | awk '{print substr($2, 1, length($2)-1)","$5","$7","$9}'
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I try many time and come up with the same solution as you. :D

Comment: But I want to use general regex. Please take a look at my question again (just updated) :D

Comment: You don't need grep when you're using awk and see http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html

Answer (score 1):

With tr and awk:

```
tr -cd '0-9 .\n' <file | awk 'NF>1 && NF=4' OFS=","
```

> Remove all characters from file but digits 0-9, space, dot and newline with `tr` and output remaining characters to awk command. If then a row contains more than one column (`NF>1`) reduce number of columns to four (`NF=4`).

Output:

```
5,20,35265.85,35265.85
10,20,35965.67,35965.67
15,20,35233.82,35233.82
20,20,35239.05,35239.25
25,20,37188.61,37188.41
30,20,36622.32,36622.32
35,20,36538.27,36538.27
```

---

See: [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)